# Multiple Reason Tables used as a definition for 1 Table with one reason Column

Tags: sql

I have a requirement I have 1 table which has a container with a qty and a Reason_ID.

Problem is that there are 5 different Reason tables that can define the reason but the container table has only one column. So the container table looks like the follow:

| Container Name | Qty | ReasonID | ContainerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A222 | 50 | LR111 | AAA |
| A888 | 75 | LR222 | BBB |
| B333 | 32 | BR111 | CCC |
| B555 | 44 | SR111 | DDD |
| C777 | 77 | BR333 | EEE |

The Reason Codes are as follows:

| Loss_ReasonID | Definition | ReasonID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LR111 | Warped | LR111 |
| LR222 | Discolor | LR222 |

| Bonus_ReasonID | Definition | ReasonID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BR111 | Extra Production | BR111 |
| BR222 | Duplicate Order | BR222 |

| Scrap_ReasonID | Definition | ReasonID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SR111 | Warping | SR111 |
| SR222 | Chipping | SR222 |

I tried joining the container table with the reason ID but I kept getting blanks.

Is there anyway to create a table that looks like below:

| Container Name | Qty | Reason | ContainerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A222 | 50 | Warped | AAA |
| A888 | 75 | Discolor | BBB |
| B333 | 32 | Extra Production | CCC |
| B555 | 44 | Warping | DDD |
| C777 | 77 | Duplicate Order | EEE |

I spent a few hours trying many things but I am at a loss.

I would really appreciate your guidance. Again I apologize but this is a sample of the "custom" system that was build and it is bad.
Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You that *three* reference tables in one column.  You can use multiple `left join`s:

```
select c.*,
       coalesce(lr.definition, br.definition, sr.definition) as reason
from containers c left join
     loss_reasons lr
     on c.reasonid = lr.reasonid left join
     bonus_reasons br
     on c.reasonid = br.reasonid left join
     scrap_reasons sr
     on c.reasonid = sr.reasonid;
```

I would recommend that you rethink the data model.  Put all the reasons into a single table with a "category" for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the three reason tables being just one table using a sub-query and `union all`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  container
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ReasonID, Definition FROM loss_reason
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ReasonID, Definition FROM bonus_reason
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ReasonID, Definition FROM scrap_reason
)
  AS reason
    ON reason.ReasonID = container.ReasonID
```

You can also go one step further and add a new column to the sub-query giving a `ReasonType`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  container
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ReasonID, Definition, 'loss'  AS ReasonType FROM loss_reason
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ReasonID, Definition, 'bonus' AS ReasonType FROM bonus_reason
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ReasonID, Definition, 'scrap' AS ReasonType FROM scrap_reason
)
  AS reason
    ON reason.ReasonID = container.ReasonID
```